# how to get Unique data from one table and the other

Tags: sql, join

If I want to display `Order_Number data1 data2 data3` (most current by date changed OtherData1, OtherData2, OtherData3) `date_changed` the problem is I wasn't just one line, I was getting multiple lines for each order number.

What I would love to get is

```
1, a, f,q, cc,ccc,abc, 12/2/2014, bob
3, c, b,h, aa,aaa,abc, 12/2/2014, bob
```

Thanks!

I was working with

```
SELECT 
    t.Order_Number, 
    cr.data1, cr.data2, cr.data3,   
    t.OtherData1, t.OtherData2, t.OtherData3,
    x.date_changed, cr.name

FROM 
   (SELECT 
        Order_Number, 
        Max(date_changed) as date_changed 
    FROM 
        table2 
    GROUP BY 
        Order_Number) x
JOIN
    table2 t ON x.date_changed = t.date_changed
LEFT JOIN
    table1 cr ON x.Order_Number = cr.Order_Number
WHERE cr.name = 'bob'
```

Here are example tables.

`Table1`:

```
Order_Number    data1   data2   data3   name
    1            a        f      q       bob
    2            b        g      g       john
    3            c        b      h       bob    
    4            d        s      j       john
```

`Table2`:

```
Order_Number    date_changed    OtherData1  OtherData2  OtherData3
   1             11/30/2014        aa         aaa         abc
   1             12/1/2014         bb         bbb         def
   1             12/2/2014         cc         ccc         abc
   3             12/1/2014         dd         aaa         def
   2             11/30/2014        dd         bbb         abc
   2             12/1/2014         ss         ccc         def
   3             12/2/2014         aa         aaa         abc
   4             11/26/2014        fc         wer         wsd
```

Comment: is conf_log and table2 are same?

Comment: yes I accidentally didnt get it changed too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Join to config_log (Table2) needs to include the entire composite key if you want to retrieve unique rows.

```
JOIN
    conf_log t ON x.date_changed = t.date_changed
    And x.Order_Number = t.Order_number
```

Comment: I get doubles when I add your line (better then the LOTS more) but if I use just 
 
     select Order_Number, Max(date_changed) as date_changed from table2 group by Order_Number 

I get the same unique entries I need (but not all the data) as I would get if I use 

     select distinct Order_Number from table2 

 But the minute I try to add OtherData1 etc I get doubles.

Comment: Are there any other fields in Table2 to identify a unique row?  If there are multiple date/id's that match in Table2 what other criteria could you use to select one, or is a Select Top 1 sufficient (which could be done with a sub-query or CTE?

Comment: no that is what table2 looks like just lots more data. Am I making this way to hard? Basicly I want to select all orders and their data for bob from table 1 and use that Order number to select all the most current data for each order from table 2

Comment: I just found some weird data in table 2. I found rows with identical everything including timestamps that would be throwing off my results.

Comment: with your sample data, the above query works. i just tried. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0751f5/5 , can you accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have 2 sub querys:

```
SELECT 
    Data.Order_Number, 
    Data.data1, Data.data2, Data.data3,   
    Data.OtherData1, Data.OtherData2, Data.OtherData3,
    Data.date_changed, Data.name
  FROM 
   (SELECT 
        Order_Number, 
        Max(date_changed) as date_changed 
    FROM 
        table2 
    GROUP BY 
        Order_Number) x
JOIN (SELECT 
    t.Order_Number, 
    cr.data1, cr.data2, cr.data3,   
    t.OtherData1, t.OtherData2, t.OtherData3,
    t.date_changed, cr.name
    FROM table2 t 
    JOIN table1 cr 
    ON t.Order_Number = cr.Order_Number) AS Data
ON x.date_changed = data.date_changed
AND x.Order_Number = data.Order_number
WHERE cr.name = 'bob'
```

The fact that you had cr.name in the where clause means the LEFT JOIN had the same affect as just JOIN.